Проблема с веткой Firebase Realtime Database
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы пользователи могли между собой общаться. Реализовал страницу сообщении, но когда дело доходит до записи данных в базу, то происходит странное, само по себе перекидывает на страницу профиля. Думал дело в коде и перебрал полностью, но не смог найти. Выяснил, что проблема в ветке базы. К примеру, если я записываю данные в ветку "Test" то все работает отлично, но когда записываю в ветку "Users" происходит эта ошибка.
Непонятно что делать
